# Why do I see results on my Google Analytics portal even before I run my app?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I got a new Google Analytics ID for my Android app (a game) in development (unreleased) around **a week ago**.

Only **today**, I integrated Google Analytics SDK into my game, tested it and made it send events.

For the first time, I opened my Google Analytics portal for my game and much to my astonishment, it has recorded app "views" and "sessions" from last week even before I integrated the SDK into my game (which is still unreleased).
It has recorded 40 "new users" yesterday. It doesn't make any sense.

Is there an explanation for this?

PS: Under "top device models", it shows iPhone which is impossible since my game doesn't work on iPhone.

I did check to ensure that this is the right GA ID and there is no doubt that my game is correctly associated with the GA ID.

Comment: Have you checked the referrals reports to see where traffic "comes from"? Possibly spam activity but will need to confirm.

Comment: @nyuen, the traffic has come from random countries not including my own. What does spam activity mean?

Comment: Can you do more research and see the referrers, just so we're sure it's spam traffic? (Wouldn't want to try fixing a problem that doesn't exist, thought it's highly likely you have received spam hits.)

Comment: @nyuen sure I'll do that. But if it's a website I would understand spam traffic. But how can an unreleased Android app get visitors (spam included)? How can people even access my app?

Comment: That's the very nature  of this type is spam! They are not  real visits and they just use your property ID without ever accessing your app or page.

Comment: @nyuen yes, it is spam traffic. It is a "event-tracking.com" that's the referrer. I added a filter. But I still the *old data* from that source in dashboard. Is there a way to remove this completely? Also, if you can write all this as an answer, I would happily accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting this on an app that's only running in my simulator (no one has it yet), clearly the app id is being targeted. This is pathetic on Google's part, not to make these harder to generate. Or perhaps they give out old ones again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing are the activities of spam "visits", where the hits don't actually visit your site but rather simply, and agnostically, target your property ID. So whether you have a web app or a native mobile app, you may be hit with these "visits". You will need to set up filters to prevent these activities from affecting your data, including a filter to only allow hits from a white listed set of valid hostnames and a filter on the campaign source. This article has some great tips on how to set those up: http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/12/removing-referral-spam-google-analytics/