# Google Analytics "to use this feature visit: Event-Tracking.com"

Tags: google-analytics, spam, spam-prevention, referrer-spam

Why am I seeing `"to use this feature visit: Event-Tracking.com"` along with my other Event tracking data? I searched the web but found no answers. What is it and why is it there? Using Universal(latest). Example event tracking for a download:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Baseball', 'Download', '1977');"
```

I see analytic data for the above, but can't figure out why the `"to use this feature visit: Event-Tracking.com"` is posted too.

Comment: This is a kind of referral spam. They want to trick you into visiting the url (which is a copy of a bit of Google documentation plus some advertising, plus it may or may not contain malware). Use a filter on your data view to exclude events with "category contains Event-Tracking.com" (won't work for data that's already collected).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I see results on my Google Analytics portal even before I run my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613077/why-do-i-see-results-on-my-google-analytics-portal-even-before-i-run-my-app)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the filter and that has solved the issue. Bummer that it still displays that collected data.

Answer (score 1):

Eike's comment is the answer.  Here is how to set the event filter.

1. In Google Analytics click **Admin** and then under the View column find **Filters**.
2. Add a new filter with **Custom** type.
3. Choose **Exclude** and in the option type "event" and select Event Category.
4. Paste in whatever garbage the spammers filled your account with.
5. **Verify the filter** to see if there are matches on your data set before saving the new filter.  Note that any **filters permanently delete the GA data** from the account. Changes from applying a filter cannot be reversed.

[image]